# SSIS - importing identical data from multiple databases

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I want to copy and merge data from tables with identical structure (in a number of different source databases) to a single table of similar structure in a destination database. From time to time I need to add or remove a source database.

This is currently achieved using a Data Flow Task containing an OLEDB source with a SQL query within which there is a UNION for each of the databases I am extracting from. There is quite a lot of SQL within each UNION so, if I need to add fields, I need to add the same additional SQL to each UNION. Similarly, when I add or remove a source database I need to add or remove a UNION.

I was hoping that, rather than use such a UNION with a lot of duplicated code, I could, instead, use a Foreach Loop Container that executes SQL contained in a variable using parameters to substitute the name of the database and other database dependent items within the SQL on each iteration but I hit problems with that as I assume the Data Flow Task within the loop could not interpret the incoming fields because of the use what is effectively dynamic SQL.

Any suggestions as to how I might best achieve this without duplicating a lot of SQL?

Comment: Build the SQL in your expression (or any place outside the Execute SQL script task) and make sure it gets already formulated to your Script Task.

Comment: Is an identical query run in each database? If so then your SQL is static. It's just the connection string that changes. If all of these databases are on the same server then you can just write it all in a stored procedure

Comment: are all tables present in the same server?

Comment: The query is not absolutely identical because I need to add a database dependent prefix to each Customer Code. The tables are on the same server but in different databases.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have your loop figured out for moving from database to database. As long as the table schemas are identical (other than names as noted) from database to database, this should work for you.

Inside the For Each Loop container, create either a Script Task or an Execute SQL Task, whichever you're more comfortable working with.

Use that task to dynamically generate the SQL of your OLE DB Source query, changing the Customer Code prefix for each iteration. Assign the SQL text to a variable, either directly in a Script Task, or by assigning the Result Set of your Execute SQL Task (the result set being the query text) to a variable.

Inside your Data Flow Task, in the OLE DB Source, under Data Access Mode select "SQL Command from variable". Select the variable that you populated with your query in the last task.

You'll also need to handle changing the connection string between iterations, but, again, it sounds like you have a handle on that part already.

Comment: Thanks Eric. Mostly, that's what I'm trying to do (and using Execute SQL Task rather than Script). I think the difference is that I am not changing the connection between iterations because the variable content is changing on each iteration to explicitly address the appropriate database - e.g. SELECT ? + CustomerCode, * FROM ?.dbo.MyTable where the two ? are substituted with prefix and database name. Do you think I would resolve the issue by removing the database name substitution?